# Django select_related doesn't show all fields, but raw SQL does

Tags: django, join, orm

I have a table of hosts, and a table of parameters, with a foreign key linking the parameters back to hosts. I want to select all the hosts, and the parameter "kernelversion".

```
>>> q = Parameter.objects.filter(name__exact='kernelrelease').select_related('host')[:1]
```

This is the SQL query it shows will use, notice it's selecting all the fields from inventory_host, however only inventory_parameter columns are shown in the final QuerySet

```
>>> print(q.query)
SELECT `inventory_parameter`.`id`, `inventory_parameter`.`name`, `inventory_parameter`.`value`, `inventory_parameter`.`host_id`, `inventory_host`.`id`, `inventory_host`.`certname`, `inventory_host`.`report_timestamp`, `inventory_host`.`role`, `inventory_host`.`ipaddress`, `inventory_host`.`operatingsystemrelease`, `inventory_host`.`manufacturer`, `inventory_host`.`productname`, `inventory_host`.`alive`, `inventory_host`.`datacenter_id` FROM `inventory_parameter` INNER JOIN `inventory_host` ON (`inventory_parameter`.`host_id` = `inventory_host`.`id`) WHERE `inventory_parameter`.`name` = kernelrelease ORDER BY `inventory_parameter`.`name` ASC  LIMIT 1

>>> q.values()
<QuerySet [{'id': 133376, 'name': 'kernelrelease', 'value': '2.6.32-754.3.5.el6.x86_64', 'host_id': 4061}]>
```

I tried to run the SQL query above manually, and it provides all the results it should. Why is django removing all the inventory_host columns from the output?

```
MariaDB [opstools]> SELECT `inventory_parameter`.`id`, `inventory_parameter`.`name`, `inventory_parameter`.`value`, `inventory_parameter`.`host_id`, `inventory_host`.`id`, `inventory_host`.`certname`, `inventory_host`.`report_timestamp`, `inventory_host`.`role`, `inventory_host`.`ipaddress`, `inventory_host`.`operatingsystemrelease`, `inventory_host`.`manufacturer`, `inventory_host`.`productname`, `inventory_host`.`alive`, `inventory_host`.`datacenter_id` FROM `inventory_parameter` INNER JOIN `inventory_host` ON (`inventory_parameter`.`host_id` = `inventory_host`.`id`) WHERE `inventory_parameter`.`name` = 'kernelrelease' AND host_id = 4061 ORDER BY `inventory_parameter`.`name` ASC  LIMIT 1\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
                    id: 133376
                  name: kernelrelease
                 value: 2.6.32-754.3.5.el6.x86_64
               host_id: 4061
                    id: 4061
              certname: myhost001.sub.domain.com
      report_timestamp: 2020-10-09 11:12:33.765000
                  role: qwerty
             ipaddress: 10.1.108.53
operatingsystemrelease: 6.10
          manufacturer: VMware, Inc.
           productname: VMware Virtual Platform
                 alive: 1
         datacenter_id: 3
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: `.select_related` items will *not* be in `.values()`. `.select_related` is used to populated objects for a `ForeignKey`.

Comment: OP, I recommend reading the django documentation on select_related; it's not used for what you're assuming it's used for, so reading the docs will help clarify.

Comment: Can someone please help put me on the right track for what kind of ORM query gives me all hosts from hosts table, and their value from the parameter table where "parameter.name = kernelversion"

Answer (score 0):

It seems the Django query was correct, and all the data was there, but `.values()` didn't show it all. If I had done `.values('value', 'host__certname')` it would have shown 2 columns, `value` from the `Parameters` table and `certname` from the `Host` table because then I'm telling Django to give me data from a FK related table.

As the people in the comments to my question hinted at with their RTFM suggestions, Django automatically follows all foreign key relationships, so if I have `Parameter -> Host -> Datacenter`, with a FK linking them up that chain, selecting a `Parameter` allows me to access the values from `Host` and `Datacenter` as well, **automatically**. However, it does more SQL queries behind the scenes when these values are called, so to avoid doing a SQL query for each row, you can `select_related` to get all the values from those FK relationships on the first query, and it runs much less queries.

As a result of the way Django follows FK relationships, it seems like my query couldn't start with Host if that table is in the "middle" of a FK relationship like `Parameter -> Host -> Datacenter`. In order to do "reverse" key from `Host -> Parameter` you'd need the `_set` as explained here - [reverse related object lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#related-objects)